# using list comprehension not able to perform comparison how can i fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x

In list comprehension , using if in order to get the desired result but i am getting an error .I am not able to typecast the variable into integer from char.

Tried this code works well

```
list1=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
list2=[x for x in list1 if x<5 ]
print(list2)
```

But getting it done in one line does not

```
list1=[int(x) for x in input().split() if x<5]
```

or

```
list1=[x for int(x) in input().split() if x<5]
```

does not work

list1 should print all values less than 5.

Example
User input: 2 5 6 8

```
print(list1)
```

should give result
     [2,5]

Comment: It may be easier to see why it "does not work" by doing a simple substitution: `[x for x in [int(y) for y in input().split()] if x<5 ]` (your first snippet) vs `[int(x) for x in input().split() if x<5]` (your second snippet). It's clear here that in the former case, `x` is an integer, coming from the nested list-comp; whereas in the latter case, `x` is a string.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are comparing a splitted string and an integer (5). Try converting to `int` type before checking with the `if` statement. Now both should work. Also, as pointed out by @prashantrana, given your output, it seems you need `<=5` instead of `<5`

If you want a list of strings, then use

```
list1=[x for x in input().split() if int(x)<=5]
```

If you want a list of integers, then use

```
list1=[int(x) for x in input().split() if int(x)<=5]
```

Comment: @prashantrana: Sure. Thanks for the hint. I read "less than 5" and used the if statement from the post. :)

Comment: in output Op want [2,5] so , i guess he didn't clarify in statement earlier

Comment: @prashantrana: Yes, I added this point in my answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The if is evaluated before the int conversion. So you are trying to compare 5 to a string. The expected fix can be found in the other answers. Here's an alternative.

Because *you can*.

```py
s = '2 5 6 8'
i = list(filter(lambda i: i<=5, map(int, s.split())))
```